# MySQL INNER JOINs, WHERE CLAUSE not working

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a database with 3 tables.
content
page
page_content

page contains id, metadata stuff and so on
content contains headline, bodytext and so on
page_content contains mapping for the ids

Currently it's all done using an ORM solution, but I want to switch to plain mysql.
So I took a query builder, which gave me:

```
 Select
    cms.content.title,
    cms.content.headline,
    cms.content.bodytext,cms.page.pageID
    From
    cms.page 
    Inner Join
    cms.page_content On cms.page_content.pageID = cms.page.pageID 
    Inner Join
    cms.content On cms.page_content.contentID = cms.content.contentID
```

This shows same like just

```
select * from content
```

So I tried to add a WHERE Clause to the end.

```
 Select
    cms.content.title,
    cms.content.headline,
    cms.content.bodytext,cms.page.pageID
    From
    cms.page 
    Inner Join
    cms.page_content On cms.page_content.pageID = cms.page.pageID 
    Inner Join
    cms.content On cms.page_content.contentID = cms.content.contentID
   WHERE cms.page.pageID=1
```

But now it returns nothing.

Comment: Do you have any data for pageID of 1, which is on page_content and content? SQL wise what you have written should work.

Comment: Yes, I have entries for pageID 1.
phpMyAdmin doesn't show "query returned 0 results" it just says "query was successfully executed"

Comment: Shame on me. I have a page ID 1, but this page has no content. Page ID 2 works, like expected.

Comment: It is always the simple things that trip us up. Glad you found the problem.